# PHP implementation of pbkdf2 exhausts memory on linux but not on windows

Tags: php, linux, hash

I have a php application which calls to hash_pbkdf2 to encode passwords prior to store them in the database, using a salt.

The problem is that, when I call that function in Windows (WAMPServer 2.5) it works perfectly, but when I clone the application to a Linux Mint 17 it uses up to 70000GB of memory. It does 20000 iterations, though modifiying the number of iterations does not change the error message that it gives (so I suppose the amount of memory it uses is also the same), which is

PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 69815158964224 bytes) in XXX

The version of Apache2 is up-to-date, so as the PHP5 version. Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is the amount of memory available/allowed the same in both platforms?

Comment: It is the default in both platforms, so I suppose yes. Anyways, in Linux is requesting 70000GB...

Comment: Please, do this; `echo ini_get('memory_limit');` In both platforms, just to be sure... :)

Comment: It shows, in both platforms, "128M".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to reproduce this with the following minimal test-case in 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13 using the Apache2 module.

```
<?php

$a = [];

hash_pbkdf2('sha256', 'password', 'salt', 1);
```

As far as I can tell there are multiple bugs in the PHP 5.5 `hash_pbkdf2` implementation on Ubuntu, as in the CLI version we are experiencing a timing problem I described in this post:

[PHP hash_pbkdf2 takes orders of magnitude longer on AWS instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126113/php-hash-pbkdf2-takes-orders-of-magnitude-longer-on-aws-instances)

Unfortunately, PHP 5.5 is only receiving security updates, so I can't open a bug.  As far as I can tell, it's fixed in PHP 5.6 so my recommendation would be to upgrade to it - you can use this PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-5.6.