# PHP hash_pbkdf2 takes orders of magnitude longer on AWS instances

Tags: php, performance, amazon-web-services, cryptography, pbkdf2

We wanted to benchmark the hash_pbkdf2 function in PHP to select an appropriate number of iterations for our application to use.

When I ran my benchmark script on an m4.large AWS instance, it took five orders of magnitude longer to run than it does on my laptop.

This Gist shows the script I am using, and the results I get from an m4.large instance (under load), a t2.micro instance (with full CPU credits and no load) and three different speed Intel i7 laptops.

https://gist.github.com/roberthl/301a3fb0a32baf057806

You can see the 100,000 iterations take <200ms on the i7 laptops, but just a single iteration takes that long on the AWS instances.

I've included the PHP versions, and an OpenSSL benchmark that shows sha256 taking a comparable amount of time on both the AWS instances and an i7 laptop (and a rudimentary benchmark of the PHP hash function also showed this) - suggesting it is specifically related to the PBKDF2 operation.

What causes this to happen, and how can I speed it up?

Comment: Just a guess: the pbkdf2 function uses plain PHP - also for the hash, the hash uses native code. They may not want to upgrade that; pbkdf2 would take a lot of time on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the AWS instances are using the oldest PHP version of everything in your GIST.  That can't be great.

If you can, find a Portable PHP product of recent vintage and install and benchmark it instead.

Additionally, you can benchmark a variety of PBKDF2 implementations from [my Github repository](https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords?tab=repositories), including PolarSSL, OpenSSL, and Crypto++ based versions, all with identical interfaces for the command line and source code.